# Tab Bar Controller disappears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm currently working on an iOS app in Xcode.

I have a few View Controllers that are part of a tab bar controller. I also have another view controller, that I access with a push from a button on one of the tabs (modal segue). I also have a back button on this extra view which is also a segue that leads back to the view controller where we came from.

However, when I press this back button, and come back on the view controller that was part of the tab controller, the tab bar at the bottom is no longer displayed. 
Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will help you

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but my Tab Bar still won't show up.. Maybe a screenshot will help? http://i.imgur.com/4gEUtPc.png

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;` when you are popping back to the viewcontroller.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.. I added this in my viewDidAppear, right?